# Deserializing missing Json fields in F#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, serialization, f#, json.net

I have a WebApi written in F# and I need to add some more fields to the record it transmits and accepts. Data is transmitted as Json using the Newtonsoft.Json library.

This is the record:

```
[<DataContract(Name="Foo")>]
[<CLIMutable>]
type Foo =
    {
        [<DataMember>] Name: String
        [<DataMember>] Time: DateTimeOffset
        [<DataMember>] Status : String
        [<DataMember>] Newfield : int64 array // new
        [<DataMember>] OptionalField : DateTimeOffset option // new
    }
```

So the Json I'm receiving from looks like

```
{
    "Name":"Bob",
    "Time":"2017-12-22 06:00:00",
    "Status":"OK",
}
```

With the new fields missing. With the OptionalField it may be purposefully omitted.

However when this gets deserialized, Newfield & OptionalField are set to **null**, which is bad in F# land.

```
let! content = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

let foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(content)
```

What ability do I have to populate the field with either and **Empty array** or **None**?
Obviously in this case I could just inspect the created item and fix it, but this is just an example of a wider problem. I'd like some kind of generic solution that can be applied in one place (a JsonConverter, attributes on the new members etc) - rather than needing to inspect every field it should be fixed after deserializing.

Comment: `None` is `null`.